# How to get pixel data from canvas which contains the screenshot generated by a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a very simple color picker chrome extension. The idea is simple.

1. make use of the captureVisibleTab API provided by chrome to get screenshot of current page at regular intervals.
2. load this screenshot in a canvas and then use get getImageData method for canvas context and display color values of the pixel based on the mouse coordinates.

I thought the idea was fairly simple to implement, but it actually did not turn out so well. Any help with the following snippets would be helpful:

background.js (working perfectly!)

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == 'capture') {
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, null, function(dataUrl) {
            sendResponse({ imageUrl: dataUrl });
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

content_script.js

```
function fill_canvas(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: 'capture'}, function(response) {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width= $(window).width();
        canvas.width= $(window).height();
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.onLoad = function(){
            canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }  
        img.src = response.imageUrl;
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    fill_canvas();
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        pixelData   = canvasContext.getImageData(e.offsetX,e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        console.log(pixelData);
    });
});
```

**Please expect the surrounding code to be working correctly (like the simple activate extension button) and all relevant permissions granted in the manifest.**

The output generated for pixelData looks Like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, byteLength: 4, byteOffset: 0, buffer: ArrayBuffer, subarray: function, set: function…]
```

which on opening contains lot's of info, except the one I need.

Cheers!

Comment: You state we should expect the surrounding code to work correctly, but I still need to ask if you have double-checked that response.imageUrl actually contain any data? (what does it contain if you console.log(response.imageUrl) it).

Comment: hi @Ken-AbdiasSoftware it contains the dataurl, which opens as image in browser. It is a screenshot of current visible area in tab.

please refer to this paste http://pastebin.com/HMTZdP2D and try opening the data url in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As javascript is case-sensitive your `onLoad` will never kick in (no camel-case for events). Try to lower-case it:

```
// onload not onLoad
img.onload = function(){
    canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

I also noticed you put the canvas and context on the global scope (window). I would guess (I am not familiar with Chrome's extension api) that the api prevents or isolates the window object (seals or freezes it).

Modify these and I am pretty sure, wo/ testing, it would work:

```
//use 'var' in front
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

or define them outside this function (you don't show if you do this already).

Comment: even I thought so. but that generates a Uncaught TypeError: Type error content_script.js:<line>
img.onload

Comment: thanks @Ken, worked. To some extent, but could give me exact details of colors, blurts out random colors generally white. Please help me with it. https://github.com/whizzzkid/ColorHelper-Chrome

Comment: @whizzzkid If you feel the answer was correct you can mark it correct below the counter top-left.

Comment: please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841844/unable-to-get-correct-data-from-canvas-getimagedata